# How to set NSManagedObjectID manually?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, mongodb, nsmanagedobject

I want to sync the Core Data on iPhone with MongoDB on Sinatra server.

When the iPhone gets a message from the Node.js chat server, the message contains the sender's BSON ObjectId (a string). For the iPhone to store this message, I find the user with that same Id in Core Data. I want to be able to do something like `objectWithID`. In other words, I want to set the NSManagedObjectIDs to be the same as the MongoDB BSON ObjectIds. The other thing I would check is if there are no users with the sender's id in the managedObjectContext, I will fetch him from the persistentStore, and if he's not there, I'll create him. This is a lot to do just to maintain the relationship between Message and Sender. Maybe I should just store the sender attribute of the Message object as his BSON ObjectId as a string instead of as a User NSManagedObject.

What do you recommend? Should I just use MongoDB on the iPhone too? I just realized there's an Objective-C driver for it. But I was just starting to get the hang of Core Data, and it has cool things (like undo support) that I might want to use... Right now, I'm just using it for simple fetching & persistent storage, so I could replace it. But I plan to implement undo support in the future, just because I think that's good usability. I prefer the option to undo than having to answer a confirmation pop-up, e.g., I like how GMail lets you undo a send or undo a deletion of messages, etc.

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set the objectID of a core data object manually. You'll probably want to add an attribute called externalID or something where you store the ID you got from the server.

See [this article](http://inessential.com/2010/02/26/on_switching_away_from_core_data) for some thoughts on whether or not to use Core Data. Note that the author's recommendation is to stick with Core Data in almost all cases.

Comment: That's a great article.  I had a similar problem to solve, and I stuck with Core Data with a `remoteID` Int32 attribute.  Performance is definitely a problem, with the bottleneck being doing a fetch for each item keyed on remoteID to see if it's already in the MOC.  100 or so such fetches is taking about 1 second on iPhone 3GS but 5 seconds on the first-gen iPhone.  Possible improvements is to fetch many items at once using an `IN` predicate, and doing it in a background thread.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I think I'm going to stick with Core Data and do what you suggest, esp. since I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController`, which I forgot to mention in my question.